# d3.js switch json map depending on year

Tags: json, maps, d3.js, geojson

Here is my d3.js map on bl.ocks http://bl.ocks.org/textplusdata/f64f54dd8c1a0b632ed5

On the raw version you can use arrow keys or an autoplay to cycle through year data to show changes over time.

My question is this. How can I get a different world json file to load depending on the year? Before 1991 the old Soviet Union exists but doesn't show up in the data.

I already have two jsons uploaded, one with the old soviet union in it and the other one without.

```
// The map

var maptype;
if ( parseInt(year) < 1991) maptype = world_countriesold;
if ( parseInt(year) > 1991) maptype = world_countries;


var countries = d3.select("g#countries").empty() ?
chart.append("g").attr("id", "countries") : d3.select("g#countries"),
country = countries
.selectAll("path")
.data(maptype.features);
country
.enter()
.append("path")
.classed("country", true)
// changed { return d.id; } to { return d.ISO1AL3; } to look up 3-letter country code in c-shapes json
.attr("id", function(d,i) { return d.id; })
// changed { return d.properties.name; } to { return d.properties.CNTRY_NAME; } to return correct field in c-shapes json
.attr("title", function(d,i) { return d.properties.name; })
.attr("d", path);
```

I guess I have just put the "if" statement in the wrong place, but I don't know how to force the trigger...

Answer (score 0):

After the initial creation of the paths, you need to update the existing ones when passing in new data. Your code for the update should look something like

```
country = countries.selectAll("path")
  .data(maptype.features);

country.enter()
  .append("path");
country.classed("country", true)
  .attr("id", function(d,i) { return d.id; })
  .attr("title", function(d,i) { return d.properties.name; })
  .attr("d", path);
country.exit().remove();
```

You need to call this block of code every time you change `maptype`, i.e. from within the `if` statement blocks.